# Overloading operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dynamic-cast

Can someone explain how this overloaded operator is called? I understand what the dynamic cast and the conditional ternary do, but I don't understand the operator.

header file:

```
 // ------------------------------------------------------
Class Base
{
public:
  Base ();
  operator Derived &();
private:
  Base * me;
}
//--------------------------------------------------
Class Derived : public Base
{
public:
Derived ()
}
//----------------------------------------------------
inline Base::operator Derived &() {return *(dynamic_cast<Derived *>(me?me:this));}
```

Source file:

```
Base::Base()
{
me = new Derived()
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a CRTP instead? Completely unclear how your code can work without `Base` knows about every `Derived` inheriting from it.

Comment: Actually I don't see that `Base class` is polymorphic so it could be problem with `dynamic_cast`

Comment: Could you explain a little be more?

Comment: This is part of much larger code, I tried to reduce it for asking this question.

Comment: It's a conversion operator

Comment: That's hideous. If the dynamic_cast fails, it dereferences a null pointer (in the sense of converting it to a reference). Anyway, `operator Derived &` is supposed to be a user-defined conversion to a reference to Derived. Note you can find all the operator overloads [documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) (it's useful to know where to look since they're hard to search for by name)

Comment: Thanks Christophe and Useless. Let say that I want to call that conversion operator how I would do it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `operator Derived &()` is a conversion operator:

> **12.3.2/1** A member function of a class X having no parameters with a name of the form
>       conversion-function-id:
>           operator conversion-type-id
>       (...)
>
> specifies a conversion from X to the type specified by the
>   conversion-type-id. Such functions are called conversion functions. No
>   return type can be specified.

So it converts a `Base` object into a reference to `Derived`.

**Attention:** This kind of construct seems extremely weird and dangerous: it is a downcasting without care. If the object on which you use this operator would not be a `Derived` (for example a "pure" `Base` object or a another class derived from `Base` but not from `Derived`) the `dynamic_cast` would return a `nullptr`, which would cause UB:

> **8.3.2/5:**  (...) *Note:* in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a
>   reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by indirection
>   through a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks Christophe for editing your answer. It's very helpful.